# Most painless multi-tenancy implementation using ASP.NET, NHibernate / Fluent NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement multi-tenancy in an ASP.NET MVC application I have, that uses NHibernate. Though I have control over the database for multi-tenancy. I'm trying to figure out the best way to filter our database queries using NHibernate.

I would like to know if there is a painless way where I can append a condition (something like `WHERE InstanceID = 1`) to every CRUD query to the DB using NHibernate.

I looked at global filters. But I wasn't sure if I'm using it the right way. I tried something like this.

```
NHibernateSession.GetDefaultSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession()
.EnableFilter("instance-filter").SetParameter("InstanceId", "2");
```

But it didn't seem to work. Any good example of NHibernate global filters / any good approach of filtering all DB queries with a condition  would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been looking for the same thing for a small project of mine that's still in planning phase. The most complete implementation of using a single database that I came upon is written by [Michael Valenty](http://www.agileatwork.com/) in his blog post: [Bolt-on Multi-Tenancy in ASP.NET MVC with Unity and NHibernate: Part II – Commingled Data](http://www.agileatwork.com/bolt-on-multi-tenancy-in-asp-net-mvc-with-unity-and-nhibernate-part-ii-commingled-data/). He's also using global filters.

Just for the sake of completeness, here are the mappings he used:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <filter-def name="tenant">
        <filter-param name="id" type="System.Int32" />
    </filter-def>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And for each entity:

```
<class name="User" table="[user]">
    <id name="Id" column="user_id">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="Username" />
    <property name="Email" />

    <filter name="tenant" condition="tenant_id = :id" />
</class>
```

After that, he uses his IoC container of choice to inject the parameter value to instance of ISession.

```
session.EnableFilter("tenant").SetParameter("id", c.Resolve<Tenant>().Id);
```

There's also an interceptor to implement - to write the value of current tenant id when saving the entity (`OnSave` method), and also to check whether the given entity belongs to current tenant when loading the entity by id (`OnLoad` method). `OnLoad` override is necessary because tenant filter won't be applied when loading entity by id.

Comment: Thanks Miroslav. That definitely looks good. Different than what my google research led me to. Since my multi-tenancy implementation takes some time (where I'll need to consider performance issues and what not). I'll keep this thread open and see where the answers lead to. I will mark your post as the answer once I get the implementation working based on the NH global filters and interceptors. Thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem. It would also be great if you could share your experience with this approach once you (hopefully) implement it :)