# Building Fluent NHibernate Maps at runtime

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mirth

I am working on a project that looks at the database created by Mirth Connect v3.

In this version, tables are created at run time based on channels created.

For example, if I create a new channel, it creates an entry in a table that has a unique id. Then, using that id, a set of tables is created with that id added onto the end of the name.  ie for a channel with id 8, a table called d_ms8 (among others) is created.

All of these tables (d_ms*) have the same structure.

What I am wondering is whether or not there is a way to map this sort of thing in Fluent NHibernate.

```
    public class MapChannelStats : ClassMap<ChannelStatsObj>
{
    public const String TableName = "d_ms8";

    public MapChannelStats()
    {
        Table(TableName);

        Id(x => x.MetadataID).Column("metadata_id");
        Map(x => x.ServerID).Column("server_id");
        Map(x => x.Errored).Column("error");
        Map(x => x.ErroredLifetime).Column("error_lifetime");
        Map(x => x.Filtered).Column("filtered");
        Map(x => x.FilteredLifetime).Column("filtered_lifetime");
        Map(x => x.Received).Column("received");
        Map(x => x.ReceivedLifetime).Column("received_lifetime");
        Map(x => x.Sent).Column("sent");
        Map(x => x.SentLifetime).Column("sent_lifetime");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a difficult thing what you are asking, because I think you are not able to change the table's name at runtime. However, if you change your approach, there should be some possibilities, like:

- You could create a column to specify the tenant ID, instead of creating a whole table for it. Then, you can set a filter specifically for this column ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667467/most-painless-multi-tenancy-implementation-using-asp-net-nhibernate-fluent-nh)), which you can change like this:

  ```
  Session.EnableFilter("tenant-filter").SetParameter("TenantId", "2");
  ```
- Or you could create a database for which tenant and use a component like [Boot.Multitenancy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Boot.MultiTenancy).

Comment: Hello David.  Thanks, but unfortunately it is a database that I don't control. That is why it is a pain.

Comment: I suspect that I will have to use another technology for this part. LINQ, probably.

Comment: I see. In this case, I think you may have to use plain SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks David. That is exactly what I did.